# How to close gap between image and text?

Tags: css, html

[image]

I dont understand why I have a large gap between the second picture and the text to its right. I've attached a fiddle for the code. How do I close this gap?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Qchr/

```css
.main {
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 2px;
    -webkit-columns: 2;

}

#image {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <p id="text_l">
       &ldquo; The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our     next order!&rdquo;
    <p>
    <img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Picture of cheese" id="image">
</div>

<div class="main">
    <img src="img/cheese2.jpg" alt="Picture of cheese" id="image">
    <p id="text_r">
       &ldquo; Wow,amazing cheese selection and fast delivery! I highly  recommed you try!&rdquo;
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not an answer to this problem, but ids should be unique. You can't have two images with the same id.

Comment: Columns doesn't seem to be the right approach here.

Comment: Why are columns not the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to rewrite your code a bit... Try something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <p id="text_l">blah</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="cheese1.jpg" class="image">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <img src="cheese2.jpg" class="image odd">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="text_r">blah</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main div{
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.image {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.image.odd {float: right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Qchr/6/

Comment: Try to resize the HTML window in the fiddle and you'll see it didn't work.

Comment: @Juhana It works whatever you do to it, no gap. The image is not floated to the right, but not sure that's the desired effect. Besides, this thing shouldn't be built like this, but I answered how to close the gap.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Qchr/2/ The question is about the gap between the left image and the text next to it, not the gap between the columns.

Comment: Ah, now I see the image added to the question... ok

Comment: @Juhana do you know why musa doesn't think columns are the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WHxYM/1/)

The following CSS was added (none of the existing HTML or CSS was changed).

```
.main + .main {
    text-align: right;
}
p {
    text-align: left;
}
```